# UpdateQueryError MongoDB Array field

Tags: mongodb, mongokit

So I have a mongo object:

```py
@connection.register
class UserInformation(Document):
    structure = {
        'extra_infos':[{
            'nickname':basestring,
            'name_on_account':basestring,
        }],
        'age': int,
        'mean_distance':float,
    }
```

And I updated the doc to this

```py
@connection.register
class UserInformation(Document):
    structure = {
        'extra_infos':[{
            'nickname':basestring,
            'name_on_account':basestring,
            'email':basestring,
        }],
        'age': int,
        'mean_distance':float,
    }
```

Then I went ahead with the following migration:

```py
class UserInformationMigration(DocumentMigration):
    def allmigration01_email(self):
        self.target = {'extra_infos':{'$exists':True},'extra_infos.email':{'$exists':False}}
        self.update = {'$set':{'extra_infos.email':[]}}
```

Then I executed the following commands

```py
migration = UserInformationMigration(UserInformation)
migration.migrate_all(collection=connection['user_info'])
```

But I keep on getting the following error:

```
UpdateQueryError: 'extra_infos.email' not found in UserInformation's structure
```

What am I doing wrong? is it because extra_infos is an array? I suspect that my migration is defined incorrectly, but I am not sure how to define it differently for an array extra_infos

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. You will need to use this instead:

```
self.update = {'$set':{'extra_infos.0.email':[]}}
```

It will reference the first element in 'extra_infos'.

Comment: now I get AttributeError: 'CallableUserInformation' object has no attribute '__name__'

Answer (score 0):

The datatype of `extra_infos` is `list` and not `dict`.

One way is as suggested by @atx, but the approach seems to be a hack and not as a solution, according to me, since if it is not a list of dicts, but only one dict in the list, you may directly have a `dict`.

You may actually modify the executor field as following and need not alter your code:

`@connection.register
class UserInformation(Document):
    structure = {
        'extra_infos':{
            'nickname':basestring,
            'name_on_account':basestring,
            'email':basestring,
        },
        'age': int,
        'mean_distance':float,
    }`